# How to make page numbers to plain numbers in scrlttr2?

Tags: page-numbering, scrlttr2

I wrote a letter with multiple pages in `scrlttr2`. Now I get the page numbers "Seite 2" and so on, but I simply want "2" there.

I don't find an option how to turn this off, neither in the `scrguide.pdf` nor in the source code. This reproduces the error (I use lyx, but that doesn't matter):

```
\documentclass[ngerman,fromrule=off,addrfield=on,backaddress=off,fromalign=left,enlargefirstpage=off]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\geometry{verbose}
\pagestyle{plain}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\newif\ifletterclosed
\AtEndDocument{\ifletterclosed\else\end{letter}\fi}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.

\pagenumbering{roman}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\setkomavar{fromaddress}{from me}

\begin{letter}{to adress}

\setkomavar{date}{today}

\setkomavar{subject}{spam}

\begin{letter}{}
\LoadLetterOption{DIN}
\makeatletter
%\@setplength{refvpos}{4cm}
%\@setplength{subjectaftervskip}{1cm}
\makeatother


\opening{Dear stranger,}

\Blindtext 

\closing{Bye}

\setkomavar{signature}{My name}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Commenting `\LoadLetterOption{DIN}` doesn't help. I don't see any further options that might be related to page numberings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to redefine the `\pagemark` command:

```
\renewcommand\pagemark{\usekomafont{pagenumber}\thepage}
```

Additional remarks:

The letter-class-option file `DIN` is loaded by `scrlttr2` automatically.

I do not understand why you are nesting `letter` environments and why you are closing the outer `letter` environment using `\AtEndDocument`. So in the following MWE there is only one `letter` environment:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,backaddress=off,fromalign=left]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,verbose]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}


\pagenumbering{roman}
\renewcommand\pagemark{\usekomafont{pagenumber}\thepage}


\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}

\setkomavar{fromaddress}{from me}
\setkomavar{signature}{My name}
\setkomavar{date}{today}
\setkomavar{subject}{spam}

\begin{letter}{to adress}

  \opening{Dear stranger,}
  \Blindtext 
  \closing{Bye}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It Works! Curiously, DIN 5001 does not support that kind of page numbering ("Seite 2") in scrlttr2 with DIN option